# present progressive or not

Tags: grammar, present-continuous, progressive-aspect

I would like to know the difference between "I write" and "I'm writing". Yesterday I watched a film, and there was a sentence that ended "as I write." What surprised me is that the actor was writing. So why not "as I'm writing"?

In the film, the man who was writing did not play a writer.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could tell us more about the context. (Basically, this is about the progressive aspect, but it's tangled up with the usage of *as*.) Without context, I tend to read *as I write* as "like I write", and *as I'm writing* as "while I'm writing".

Answer (score 1):

"As I write" can mean "even as I write," which is in parallel to the stock phrase, "Even as I speak" -- something that is happening *at that same moment.*

"Even as we speak, the Martians are invading Tokyo!"

"Even as we speak, your ex-girlfriend is making out with your brother!"

"Even as I type this, someone is posting something else!"

-

Or it might be a synonym for "while I write"!

"The cat watches me as I write."

"The radio is playing as I write."

-

Or, if you are watching the anime *Princess Tutu* or reading the webcomic *Namesake*, it means that things are happening *because* you write them happening. Because in fantasy settings, Writers are dangerous that way.

"The people believe as I write [them to believe]."

"The duck dances as I write [her dancing]."

"The crow princess is eaten by her father as I write."

"The card soldier becomes friendly as I write."

Comment: The anime and webcomic usages are similar to the command "Do as I say!"

Comment: Yes, they very much are.